# How to write modular network code?

Tags: c, networking, modularity

I have an assignment in which I have to implement a few network protocols. The assignment includes communication over ideal connections (that do not lose or corrupt data) and connections that do corrupt the data. I would like to make this as modular as possible, but I can't figure out how to do it (everything seems so intertwined). Here's a list of things I have to do:

- **Sliding window**. This task assumes a perfect connection. However, I would like to abstract away this detail (implement the sliding window code such that handling the quality of the connection is some other module's responsibility).
- **Go-Back-N** protocol for an imperfect connection. Here I would like to reuse code from the previous task that involved sliding windows.
- **Selective repeat**. This sounds like it should replace the Go-Back-N module, while still working on top of the sliding window module.
- **Error detection**. This one looks like it should be independent of whether I use sliding windows, Go-Back-N or selective repeat. Yet, I can't figure out how to separate error checking from message receiving.

Maybe I can implement a layered architecture (inspired by the OSI model), but I'm not sure how to do it. I need a nudge in the right direction.

How should these different modules interact with each other? Such that Go-Back-N or Selective Repeat function independently of whether I want to fill the data link (sliding window) or not, and such that error checking is done on top of all of this, transparently.

**Edit:** One other difficulty is that some protocols (Go-Back-N, Selective Repeat, Sliding Window) require state particular to that protocol and there's no nice way to implement stateful functions in C.

Comment: Well if you have time, and can find a copy of [TCP/IP Illustrated, Vol 2: The implementation](http://www.amazon.com/TCP-IP-Illustrated-Implementation-Vol/dp/020163354X/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1364661964&sr=8-3), it goes through a complete network stack from top to bottom.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Unfortunately, time is rather short. And so is money. :P

Comment: If you don't have time to study and understand the problem space, how do you expect to solve it well?

Comment: @RandyHoward http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could work with chained functions?

Initially, you could have a `struct connection` with fields like `void (*write)(struct connection *con, char *buf, size_t len, void *data);`, `void *write_data;`, `int (*get_write_queue_size)(struct connection *con, void *data)` and `void *get_write_queue_size_data`. First, you would fill it with the functions for dealing with an ideal connection.

Then, for adding a sliding window, you would make a `struct sliding_window_connection` with all the fields from `struct connection` that you want to intercept. Then, you would move the old functions and data-pointers from the `struct connection` into the `struct sliding_window_connection`, replace the functions in the `struct connection` with the sliding window implementations and replace the data pointers in the `struct connection` with pointers to the `struct sliding_window_connection`. The new `write` could e.g. look somewhat like this:

```
void sliding_window_connection_write
      (struct connection *con, char *buf, size_t len, void *data) {
  struct sliding_window_connection *swcon = data;
  /* ... do magic for the sliding window ... */
  /* if we want the buffer to be sent now, call the lower layer like this: */
  swcon->write(con, buf, len, swcon->write_data);
}
```

For stacking go-back-n or selective repeat on top, you would then add the go-back-n or selective repeat functions the same way.

For reading, you would basically do the same – let the data bubble up through the layers and maybe manipulate or interpret it on the way.

To make this work better, you might want to add a function similar to `write` that can be used by a layer (e.g. go-back-n) to signal a lower layer (e.g. the sliding window) for purposes like "hey, please resend bytes m->n, thanks".

As error detection would have to happen on a higher level than these things, you would have to add it after the other things – the later you add something, the higher its layer.